# Generate an incremental $variable when in a for loop

Tags: php, variables, for-loop

i'd like to increment the variable within the for loop so that from "$filename" it turns into "$filename1" and then to $filename2"?

```
$filename = false;
$filename1 = false;
$filename2 = false;    

for ($i = null; $i <=2; $i++){
  $filename = $this->blabla;
}
```

Comment: Have you read about [arrays](http://php.net/array) yet?

Comment: yes i have, i'm just wondering if this could be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use variable variables:

```
${"filename".$i} = $this->blabla;
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try, something like:

```
for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){
  $ii = $i === 0 ? '' : $i;
  ${"filename$ii"} = $this->blabla;
}
```

or

```
for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){
  $ii = $i === 0 ? '' : $i;
  $f = "filename$ii";
  $$f = $this->blabla;
}
```

Comment: PHP doesn't use `+` for concatenation. But even with that fix, it's not correct.

Comment: I posted before I should have.